# Vue 3 easy data table Sonarcube Error for adding description in the table tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Used this table "vue3-easy-data-table". After validatiing the code from Sonarcube Scanner faced the issue to **add descrption in the table tag**.
[image]

My code:

```
<EasyDataTable
  :loading="loading"
   buttons-pagination
   :headers="changeheaders"
   :items="items"
   :rows-per-page="10"
   table-class-name=""
   :server-items-length="serverItemsLength"
   :empty-message="emptyMessage"
   :rows-items="[5, 10, 25, 30, 50]"
   :hide-footer="serverItemsLength == 0 ? true : false"
  >
```

How can we add the description in the code?